# How to find (distinguish) library code in disassembled ELF executable?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, elf, disassembly

In a disassembled ELF file i need to distinguish the code i wrote from the code inserted by the compiler from external libraries ( like capstone or whatever u want). I disassembled and i lost tract of calls when I get to a section called . To navigate through ELF sections I used ghidra.

Comment: Code from dynamic libraries are not in your ELF file.

Comment: Are you talking about code from `inline` functions defined in header files?  (More common in C++ but possible in C.) Compilers can choose to emit a stand-alone definition and `call` it instead of actually inlining such functions at every callsite.  But usually any library functions defined in headers will be small enough that compilers will inline them.

Comment: I need to find a way to see what code is inserted besides the code I write, that is what I am talking about. Sorry if i wrote something that confuses you

Answer (score 1):

If the binary isn't stripped, then you should be able to distinguish between the functions just via the name of the function. For example, if a function is called `main` then it's code that you wrote, and if it's called `malloc` then it's inside libc. Additionally, if the binary is dynamically linked, then external calls should be displayed as such inside GHIDRA. However, if the binary is statically linked **and** stripped then you'll just have to guess.

Comment: Yes, that is true.In Ghidra I can identify them.It creates another section called external. Tho i need to find a pattern outside ghidra so I can identify those calls in any elf and without debug info. And in ghidra all i can find are pointers to .plt ->.got -> <external>. I can't get to see the code of the function called and that is kind of what i need to do

Comment: You can disassemble the external library. You can view external libraries by running `ldd filename`.

Comment: Yes, but from what i understand some code is inserted by the compiler in my ELF. And that is what i am trying to identify, not to disassemble the external library

Comment: If you just want to disassemble your code then don't look at external calls.

Comment: I want to see what code is inserted *if any*  in my ELF besides my code